# Obtener Valores del checkbox ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

me pasa lo siguiente estoy manejando un sistema lo cual cuenta con 2 checkbox

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input id="admin" type="checkbox" class="material_checkbox" name="admin">
        <label for="admin">Administrador</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="active" type="checkbox" class="material_checkbox" name="active">
        <label for="active">Activo</label>
    </div>
```

y posteriormente necesito recibirlos en ajax como valores 1 o 0.
Cabe destacar que estoy trabajando con jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas noches, si entiendo bien ¿necesitas el valor de ambos checkboxes en un arreglo para mandar por ajax verdad?

si es asi, creo que este codigo te servira:

```
        var values = $('input:checkbox').map(function() {
        return this.value; // obtienes el valor de todos los checkboxes

        }).get();
       // Y aqui mandas los valores al archivo php
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'accion.php',
            data: { valores : values },
             //valores = [1,0]
        });
```

y en tu php seria algo asi:

```
        <?php
            $valores = $_POST["valores"];
             foreach $valor as $valores
             {
              // aqui va tu codigo
             }
          ?>
```

Saludos, cualquier duda estoy a tu disposicion

Comment: hice lo que jose sanchez garcia dijo pero aun no me salio el php me dice que esta la variable "valores" dentro de [] no esta definida.